# How can we parse JSON data in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am beginner and i am getting a JSON message from the server and the message I receive i mentioned below(i am getting json array from server) and I tried to parse my level best but no result,How can i parse above below given JSON message with below **fruit** object can some one help me please?

http://jsfiddle.net/dkv7tzs9/

```
 [
      {
        FruitId: 1,
        "Name": "Apple",

      },
      {
        FruitId: 2,
        "Name": "Orange",

      },
      {
        FruitId: 3,
        "Name": "Bananna",

      }
    ]
```

### code:

```js
 var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
            app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $window) {
            
             var fruit={
                FruitId:0,
                Name: '',
                Selected:false
                }  
                
                $scope.Fruits = [];
     
                $scope.GetValue = function () {
                    var message = "";
                    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Fruits.length; i++) {
                        if ($scope.Fruits[i].Selected) {
                            var fruitId = $scope.Fruits[i].FruitId;
                            var fruitName = $scope.Fruits[i].Name;
                            message += "Value: " + fruitId + " Text: " + fruitName + "\n";
                        }
                    }
     
                    $window.alert(message);
                }
            });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>

        <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
            <div ng-repeat="fruit in Fruits">
                <label for="chkCustomer_{{fruit.FruitId}}">
                    <input id="chkCustomer_{{fruit.FruitId}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="fruit.Selected" />
                    {{fruit.Name}}
                </label>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="Get" ng-click="GetValue()" />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the question, you wanted to parse the 3 item array, right?

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
            app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $window) {
            
            $scope.Fruits = [];
             var fruit1={FruitId:1, Name: 'Apple',Selected:false };  
             var fruit2={FruitId:2, Name: 'Orange',Selected:true };  
             var fruit3={FruitId:3, Name: 'Banana',Selected:false };  

                $scope.Fruits.push(fruit1);
                $scope.Fruits.push(fruit2);
                $scope.Fruits.push(fruit3);
      
     
                $scope.GetValue = function () {
                    var message = "";
                    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Fruits.length; i++) {
                        if ($scope.Fruits[i].Selected) {
                            var fruitId = $scope.Fruits[i].FruitId;
                            var fruitName = $scope.Fruits[i].Name;
                            message += "Value: " + fruitId + " Text: " + fruitName + "\n";
                        }
                    }
     
                    console.log(message);
                    alert(message);
                }
            });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>

        <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
            <div ng-repeat="fruit in Fruits">
                <label for="chkCustomer_{{fruit.FruitId}}">
                    <input id="chkCustomer_{{fruit.FruitId}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="fruit.Selected" />
                    {{fruit.Name}}
                </label>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="Get" ng-click="GetValue()" />
        </div>
```

Comment: then only i can access  Selected value or other wise how can i do this?

Comment: u understand i am saying?

Comment: how can we compare Selected value true or not its not there in array right?

Comment: i have defined 3 objects and pushed them in the array to make it clearer for you... when the visitor selects the checkboxes and clicks on the button... only rows with selected value as true are printed in console and on the alert

Comment: changed the code to make orange as selected by default... this should be very clear now